# C Programming, Absolute Beginner`s Guide - Chapter 19, strcat() function code doesn`t work properly

Tags: c, strcat

In C Programming - Absolute Beginner's Guide chapter 19, example 2, the program with strcat() function :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char city[15];
    char st[3];
    char fullLocation[18];

    puts("What town do you live in? ");
    gets(city);

    puts("What state do you live in? (2-letter abbreviation)");
    gets(st);

    strcat (fullLocation, city);
    strcat (fullLocation, ", ");
    strcat (fullLocation, st);

    puts("\nYou live in ");
    puts(fullLocation);

    return 0;

}
```

When I compile this program, it displays this :

compiler`s output in console window:

[image]

Any ideas or explanations why it displays those weird characters?

Comment: Try initializing `fullLocation` with the empty string.

Comment: In C, `fullLocation` is garbage because you didn't initialize it. strcat copies characters into the string starting at the null terminator. But there's no null terminator there. To make `fullLocation` a string of zero length, set the first character to 0: `fullLocation[0] = 0;` or initialize it in the declaration to "" or {0}.

Comment: I don't think you should be learning C from a guide written by an Absolute Beginner. You should find a text written by an experienced programmer.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the problem.

Comment: `strcat (fullLocation, city);` --> `strcpy (fullLocation, city);`

Comment: Don't post screenshots or links thereof! Post text as text.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you did not initialized the variables fullLocation, st and city, and your code is being tricked by garbage data.

Try to equate them to `={0}`

Answer (score 1):

As described here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/
strcat copies source into destination, starting from null character in destination string.
In your case, you have not null character in fullLocation.
You can add

```
fullLocation[0]='\0';
```

or replace the **first** strcat with a strcpy which copies without looking for a null char at destination